# How to use EJS templates in a Backbone project generated by Yeoman?

Tags: backbone.js, ejs, yeoman

Using `yeoman init backbone:all` generates the required files for a sample Backbone.JS app. Along with the MVC files for a sample application object, it also creates a folder at bbapp/app/scripts/templates with a sample ejs file called application.ejs. The Backbone View file for the sample application has a line (which is commented out):

```
//template: application
```

Uncommenting this does not work. It tries to look for an object with the name 'application' and throws an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: application is not defined. Using `yeoman init bbb` creates the Backbone Layout Manager which probably does the trick. Any ideas how I can use EJS files for templating in a project generated with `yeoman init backbone:all` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now the [generator-backbone](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) is not officially released for yeoman 1.0, but you can try it like [this](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/issues/9#issuecomment-14836816).

Today I proposed a fix for [precompiling ejs templates](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/pull/20).

That fix will precompile all the ***.ejs** files in **app/templates** to **app/scripts/templates.js**. Will update once the fix is merged to the master and the generator is officially released.

**PS :** In yeoman 1.0beta use **`yo backbone:all`** instead of `yeoman init backbone:all`